# neither electric field strength, nor intensity in boost units?

Tags: boost, boost-units

As the title suggests, I could neither find electric field strength, nor intensity in my boost/units/ folder (using Boost version: 1.67).

Do they have a naming I don't get, or is this indeed the case?

(for now, I wrote them myself, but I would have guessed that those units are quite often needed and therefore included as derived types?)

Comment: What units/dimensions are you expecting, specifically? We can't read your mind.

Comment: well, for the electric field strength in SI V/m, or in the base units: 1 length , 1 mass, -3 time, -1 current. I was a bit puzzled by the fact that their seems to be no derived type like for the electric potential